# Finding the sum of digits in c++. Different method

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and having trouble with a simple programme 
I need to find the sum of digits I can do that in python but I don't know how to do the same in c++.

```
digits = "1234"
sum = 0
for digit in digits:
    sum += int(digit)
print(sum)
```

How to do the same in c++?

I tried to do the same in c++ but ends up in a error.

```
string digits = "1234";
int sum, i;
for(i=0;i<digits.length();i++){
    sum += stoi(digits[i]);
}
```

But this doesn't work

Comment: One problem is that [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) wants a *string* not a single character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string digits = "1234";
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < digits.length(); i++){
    sum += digits[i] - '0';
}
```

Characters have their numbers (`ord`). By working with characters in C++ you actually work with these numbers (so `char` is an integer type). For `'0'` it's some number, for `'1'` it's `1 + '0'`, for `'2'` it's `2 + '0'` and so on. So by subtracting `'0'` you get the right digit.

Comment: Can you tell me why substract with `'0'`?